# How do you write a quick filter to check whether a User Picker (multiple users) contains less than 2 entries?

Tags: jira, jql

We have a User Picker for multiple users to indicate how is reviewing an issue. We always want at least 2 people reviewing issues and would like a quick filter to show all issues with 0 or 1 reviewer.

I don't know how to access the length or size property of the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `size` to access size property of a field.

```
size([User Picker Field]) <= 1
```

This returns all issues where length of User Picker Field is <= 1, thus complying with your `0 or 1 reviewer` requirement.

Edit: This was for JQL I didnt notice.